# Can a SP request on behalf of the user using SAML

Tags: security, saml, opensaml

A bit of background may help.  I'm looking to authenticate a user using SAML, but I want to maintain the look-and-feel of the login experience to the best of my ability.  I've looked into OpenSAML a bit, but not extensively since I'm not sure this can be done yet.  So, if I have a login service that can retrieve the username/password from the user, can I programmatically issue a SAML request to an IdP to authenticate said user without having to go through the entire XHTML form processing steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is more about how to Authenticate the user and less about SAML. SAML doesn't really dictate how a user gets authenticated at the IDP and it definitely doesn't handle your use case. As a 3rd Party SAM SP, it is not recommended you ever prompt a user for their credentials for security reasons since Enterprises only want users entering credentials into "Corporate branded" login pages to reduce phishing and other password based vulnerabilities. Besides, how can your customer trust that you are not storing users passwords if they are entering them on your site? Let the IDP handle the user login, it is just one of the many benefits of using SAML. HTH- Ian

Comment: Thanks Ian, this is pretty much what I expected/understood.  Regardless, I had to ask the question to ensure that my understanding was correct.  Many thanks.